# Connect Mist to ethereum-js testrpc

Tags: mist, dapps, testing

I need to test a DAPP which will run in Mist, but I don't want to run it in TestNet or MainNet, I want to run it in a [ethereum-js](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) `testrpc` instance.  Is it possible to do that?  Does anybody has tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer.  You just have to call:

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

And then you have your `web3` instance connected to your `testrpc` instance connected.

Comment: Do you have to put that in your html/javascript? Or is there a way to run it in Mist so, for example, Mist lists the accounts and their balances?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Use it as a library (make sure **testrpc** is running beforehand and **web3** is installed):

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
var TestRPC = require("ethereumjs-testrpc");
web3.setProvider(TestRPC.provider());
```

You can then [make](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) transactions to the contract.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43019/discussion-on-answer-by-sebi-connect-mist-to-ethereum-js-testrpc).

Comment: Your "moved to chat" link goes to a page not found.