# How to dump all json-rpc calls in Mist?

Tags: mist, json-rpc

Mist is an interesting wallet. I want to know all messages that Mist sends to geth, and receives from geth. Because to sniff the messages between Mist and geth is too inconvenient, my idea is to modify the source code of Mist, and then compiles/runs it.

How can I modify the source code of Mist to dump all messages communicated with geth?

Is it possible to give a parameter to enable Mist to dump all messages communicated with geth?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind working on a testnet, there's actually a very easy way to do this!

[Testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) will happily print every RPC call it receives on the terminal. [By setting mist to use testrpc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10104/trying-to-connect-mist-ethereum-wallet-with-testrpc) you can see not only every RPC call, but even details of gas usage.

Comment: Thanks to Matthew's answer. In fact, my goal is to use Mist for a specific private-net.

Comment: I have tested testrpc. The testrpc shows every jsonrpc's method, but not show params. How to show method as well as params?

Comment: I don't think testrpc has an option to show params _per se_. However, it might be easier to modify the code to do so--[this](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/blob/v3.0.0/lib/interface.js#L72-L80) appears to be the section.