# Where does web3 come from?

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript

I used [Truffle](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle) to setup a basic example dapp, which includes a [frontend javascript file](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle/blob/master/example/app/javascripts/app.js) in which I see the following lines:

```
window.onload = function() {
  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
    if (err != null) {
      alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
      return;
    }

    if (accs.length == 0) {
      alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
      return;
    }

    accounts = accs;
    account = accounts[0];

    refreshBalance();
    refreshBalances();
  });
}
```

What I don't understand is; where does `web3` come from in this context? In [the index.html file](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle/blob/master/example/app/index.html), only this javascript file is imported, and I don't see any mentioning of `web3` anywhere else.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out app.js in the ./build folder. (Run $ "truffle build" if it isn't there.)

Find lines with "web3" ... in particular = require("web3");

Truffle merges in a lot of stuff so we can be less concerned about implementation details. The built version will have a *lot* of unfamiliar looking stuff, but you should see familiar lines from your app near the end after /// END TRUFFLE BOOTSTRAP

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I believe (though I can't find a reference for this) Truffle automatically injects web3 during `truffle serve`. Theoretically, a dapp browser or a plugin like MetaMask would also inject web3, which is why you wouldn't see any reference to it--the user probably already has it.

If you want to manually include web3, you can [get it here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) (or through npm). [Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10123/1151) is my answer elsewhere on how to set up a functioning web3 manually.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just a question; is truffle now the most used development framework in ethereum land, or can you recommend others which are also good?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if truffle is the most popular, but I personally develop without a framework. It's ultimately personal choice--the field is so new that there's not much vendor buy-in, anyway.