# Connect Mist with testrpc on a Mac

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I followed this answer to connect Mist to `testrpc`: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10109/5995

The command to start Mist with arguments doesn't work on OS X so I tried this instead, which doesn't work either (Mist opens on `testnet`): `open -a /Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --args rpc localhost:8545`

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one worked straight away for me:

```
$ /Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc http://localhost:8545
```

Comment: Does no longer work as mist has switched to IPC. Work in progress for supporting IPC: https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/pull/261

Comment: @RolandKofler it works currently :) It gives a warning that it's insecure, but who cares it is testrpc.

Answer (score 2):

As for me (Using Ethereum client) macOS (Aug 2017)

```
"/Applications/Ethereum Wallet.app/Contents/MacOS/Ethereum Wallet" --rpc http://localhost:8545
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct command for the latest mist 0.9.3 -

`open -a /Applications/Mist.app --args --rpc <path/to/your/geth.ipc>`

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

> open -a /Applications/Mist.app --args --rpc < path to geth.ipc >

im using ios mojave